# JUnit 5 test with MockMvc not fetching data from database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

When making a request from Postman, data is returned but in the case of JUnit 5 testing, my API returns an empty list.

How can I make my test hit my real database and return data?

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {
                
  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;
                
  @Autowired
  WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
                
  @MockBean
  private UserService userService;
                
  @MockBean
  private UserRepository userRepository;
                
  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {            
    mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }
  
  @Test
  void getAllData() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/getAllData"))
                                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                                .andReturn();
                
    System.out.println("My Result" + result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
  }
}
```

Comment: You use mock service and mock repository. This will never hit the database. If you want to create integration test, drop mock and use change webmvctest to springboottest

Answer (score 1):

Fetching data from a real database in a unit test is not considered standard practice.
Instead, you can create your mock object which will ***'mock'*** or ***'imitate'*** the behavior of your real database.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringRunner.class)
class UserControllerTest {
            
  MockMvc mockMvc;
            
  @Mock
  private UserService userService;

  @InjectMocks
  private UserController userController;
            
  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {            
    mockMvc = standaloneSetup(userController).build();
    User user = User.builder().your_field1(FIELD_VALUE).your_field2(FIELD_VALUE).build(); //Use the fields as per your code
  }

  @Test
  void getAllData() throws Exception {
    when(userService.getAllDataForUser(USER_ID)).thenReturn(user);  //Use the method name as per your code

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/getAllData"))
                            .andExpect(status().isOk())
                            .andReturn();
            
    System.out.println("My Result" + result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
  }
}
```

Also, since you are testing the controller, you need not have a mock bean of the repository. The component that is being tested and its immediate successor(here service class) only need to be present.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your tests using some other database configuration, configured in *test/resources/application.properties* file or *.yml* file.

Probably you do not access the same database instance with the postman and the database instance with the test method.